# PDFSharp - MigraDoc : Text in a table row exceeds page length.

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

Why does my row contents truncate? I am trying to write text on the PDF using contents in Text Files. I use StreamReader to read the file, and then for each Line, i add a row. I cannot change and control the text in the file. Sometimes, a single line of text is so huge, that it cannot fit a page and when that happens, the row will not split across pages.

What is the right way to do it then? is there a max length to a row contents?

Answer (score 1):

Text in a row is not limited (except by page size).
Paragraphs outside of tables will break to the next page (while rows in a table currently do not break to the next page).

So if "a single line" sometimes needs more than one page, tables are not appropriate. Use paragraphs outside tables instead.

Comment: Well, that defeats the purpose of what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for the information anyways. I will have to use paragraphs.